# Example wanted: manually override automatic SPI class registration (Java AudioSystem), for MP3+M4A coexistence

Tags: java, audio

I am attempting to use both MP3SPI and JAAD in the same project. It is well known that JAAD tends to "hog" the SPI audio provider interface, but some people also report that MP3SPI can prevent JAAD from playing AAC/M4A files correctly as well. The workaround is to make sure that each is before the other in classpath, but this doesn't even work for me.

The closest I have been able to get is by using the last known workaround, putting JAAD last in the classpath and manually checking file extensions to specify it explicitly. With this configuration I can play AAC files, but MP3 files result in the "Resetting to invalid mark" error. If I edit the jar to remove the JAAD library from classpath entirely, MP3 files play properly.

So my question: Can somebody give me a good example (OK, any example!) of how to disable or ignore the automatic SPI injection, and manually create streams based on file extension (or other manual file type detection)?

The problem with magic is that when it goes wrong, it goes very wrong. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the answer is to use the code in the AAC example and extend it to the Mpeg code:

```
            switch (AudioFileExtension.getTypeFromName(info.path ))
            {
            case AAC:
                in = new AACAudioFileReader().getAudioInputStream(file);
                decodedInput = 
                        AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( OutputAudioFormat, in );
                break;

            case MP3:
                in = new MpegAudioFileReader().getAudioInputStream( file );
                decodedInput = 
                        AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( OutputAudioFormat, in );
                break;
```

The trick is to manually instantiate the MpegAudioFileReader() and ignore the AudioSystem entirely.